# Calculate when round object is inside an ellipse

Tags: java, mathematics

I want to calculate in java when a circle is inside an ellipse. I drew an example below:

[image: Play field]

For this particular problem, the top left corner of the field has the position `0.0f, 0.0f`. The bottom right corner has the position `1.0f, 1.0f`. The position of the bat is: `0.48f, 0.94f`. The goal is located at: `0.5f, 1.0f`, height is `0.1f` and the radius `0.4f`.

How can I calculate if the bat is inside the ellipse?  What is the general algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ellipse math is not significantly more difficult than circle math (for detecting distance from the center).

[image]

To detect if a point is inside an ellipse, you check a `(a/b)` ratio of each component of the coordinate against a known constant.  So really, it's the same as any 2-Vector distance check, except you manipulate the coordinates slightly before squaring them.

For example, if you scale the y-coordinate to the same range as the x-coordinate, you can treat it identically to circle.  Like so:

```
Vector2 puckPos = {puck_x, puck_y};
Vector2 goalCenter = {screen_height, screen_width / 2};

float a = 0.4f * screen_width;
float b = 0.1f * screen_height;

if ((
       (puckPos.y * (a / b) - goalCenter.y) ^ 2 + 
       (puckPos.x - goalCenter.x) ^ 2
    ) < a ^ 2) {

       // inside ellipse
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with: "manipulate the coordiates slightly before squaring them."? Can you maybe give an example?

Comment: To speed things along, you may also wish to keep track of a second ellipse that describes valid values for the center of the bat.

Comment: @user35774 I added some code; tell me if that makes sense.

Comment: if you add the h and k terms, you can do: if (((x-h)*(x-h)/a/a+(y-k)*(y-k)/b/b)<1) { /*yer in*/} else {/*yer not*/} //h and k are center x and center y respectively

Comment: Possibly worth noting: this is correct for point-in-ellipse, but not for doing circle-in-ellipse testing (or circle-ellipse intersection testing), which is actually a substantially harder problem.